# Custom text input formatting on TextField not working

Tags: flutter, format, textfield

Any sort of custom TextInputFormatter is not working. Whenever I specify one, the TextField stops taking input.

```
class LowerCaseFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return oldValue;
  }
}
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _inputController,
              inputFormatters: [
                LowerCaseFormatter()
              ],
            ),
            Text(_inputController.text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The formatter you are using will always return you the previous state ie 'oldValue' but you should always return newValue just apply your changes on newValue and return it

Comment: For example, if "abc" was typed in the TextField and the user just entred "d", then the oldValue will be "abc" and newValue will be "abcd". Is this the case?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CustomFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CustomFormatter();

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(text: newValue.text.toLowerCase(), selection: newValue.selection);
  }
}
```